# take input from command prompt in perl

Tags: perl, command-prompt

I am trying to write a script in which I should open a file that can be any file.

But I want to pass the name of file from the command prompt or some other way, so that I don't have to edit the script when ever the input file name changes.

Can any one help how can I do that ?

```
        open (DBC, "test.txt")|| die "cant open dbc $!";
        @dbc =  <DBC>;
        close (DBC);
```

the file is in the directory where my script is, that's why am not giving any path here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the ARGV array for getting, say, the first argument:

```
my $file = $ARGV[0];
open (DBC, $file)|| die "cant open dbc $!";
@dbc =  <DBC>;
close (DBC);
```

There are a lot of better ways to eventually do this sort of thing, like checking to make sure they passed something first:

```
if ($#ARGV == -1) {
    die "You need to supply a file name to the command";
}

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open (DBC, $file)|| die "cant open dbc $!";
@dbc =  <DBC>;
close (DBC);
```

And you can go on from there, eventually learning about the [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) and similar modules.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i'll go through Getopt::Long once again thank you for help

Comment: You're welcome.  If you're new here, you should accept the best answer you get and upvote ones that help you.  Otherwise you'll get a poor reputation and people will stop answering your questions :-)

Comment: You bet.  Welcome to the stack overflow party!

Answer (score 0):

Read [`perlop #I/O Operators`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) for a shortcut method for processing files passed from the command line.  To briefly quote from the linked documentation:

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of **sed** and **awk**, and any other Unix filter program that takes a list of filenames, doing the same to each line of input from all of them. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from *each file listed on the command line*. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `"-"`, which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames.

Basically, you can simplify your script to just the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

die "$0: No filename specified\n" if @ARGV != 1;

while (<>) {
    # Process your file line by line.

}
```